# Socket.IO: Are Emits from clients to the server private

Tags: node.js, socket.io, client, server, privacy

So here is the deal; I have a Client, that needs to send a message to the server, and that message needs to be private. My question is, when I emit something from a client, can other clients see the message, or is it directed only to the server? It's important that only the server can see that message. I do not want the other clients to be able to.

The main purpose for this is that if a client gets "hacked" or uses their console to do a socket.on statement, they must not be able to see what other clients are sending to the server.

My feeling is that client emits are directed only to the server, and only the server has the power to relay that emit (or echo) to other clients.

The Socket.IO documentation is lacking detail. Just wanted to clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Others will not see the message, *Socket.io* is **server-client** communication. By design, client can only communicate with a server, and then server broadcasts it to others if needed (of course not by default).

What you are describing is a peer-to-peer communication, but that isn't a *socket.io*.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't want peer-to-peer. Guess this is exactly what I need!

Comment: Yes, I just pointed out how it is called. *Peer-to-peer* actually is a rapidly growing topic of research and development in the last years. Welcome to *StackOverflow*